# Setting a Variable to a Cookie in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to make save a variable to a cookie with a setCookie() function, but I think there's something wrong with the function.

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
        var expires = "";
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
      }
```

I'm calling it when the page loads with this:

```
<body onload="setCookie(cpoints, 0, 99)">
```

But when I load the site and check my cookies it still says that I have no cookies, what could be wrong with this?

Comment: How do you inject this code into website?

Comment: I don't know what that means, I'm using neocities to make my site.

Comment: Add debugging to see if the code is called console.log and debugger and break points are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

your setCookie function technically works. so if you can't see your set cookies it means that your function doesn't fire on body load. I also don't know if there is an error you get but It is very likely that issue is caused by timing. It is possible that your setCookie function is not available yet when body is loaded. Idk how neocities works but below option should work for you:
Between your script tags inside  element, you declare your setCookie function add this piece as well.

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
        var expires = "";
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
      }

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  setCookie(cpoints, "0", 99);
});
```

this will run your function as soon as window is loaded.

side note for your function: keep in mind value 0 is falsy in javascript. if you call your function with setCookie(cpoints, 0, 99), number 0 will evaluate to false.